# Redux Form decorator not working, so can't initialize fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Update: the issue seems somehow tied to using the Redux-Form inside a Material-UI dialog. Maybe some prop needs to be manually specified?

---

I've been trying to migrate an application from Redux-Forms 5.x to 8.3.5.  Everything worked correctly before, but not I can't get redux-forms to work correctly with my nested forms. Now I see `Uncaught Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()` as soon as my form component comes into scope.

My app looks something like this:

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={App} />
        </Switch>
      </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>
)

App.render:
return(
/// various stuff
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/myPageComponent" component={MyPageComponent} />
        // Other routes
      </Switch>
)
```

My page Component:

```
import DialogComponent from './DialogComponent';

class MyPageComponent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }


  render() {
    const { formInfo, handleSubmit, actions } = this.props;

    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={myTheme}>
        <div>
          <Card>
            // Other stuff
          </Card>
          <DialogComponent
            open={this.state.dialog.open}
            handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
            onSubmit={this.submit}
            closeDialog={this.closeDialog}
          />
        </div>
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

MyPageComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

MyPageComponent = connect(
  state => ({
    formInfo: state.formInfo,
    initialValues: {
      name: state.detail.name,
      email: state.detail.email,
      otherInfo: nextProps.detail.otherInfo
    }
  }),
  (dispatch) => ({
    actions: bindActionCreators(MyActions, dispatch),
    dispatch
    })
)(MyPageComponent)

export default MyPageComponent;
```

And finally the form component itself:

```
// DialogComponent.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

// Widgets, etc
import Dialog from 'material-ui/Dialog';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  open: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  closeDialog: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  initialValues: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const renderTextField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error }
}) => {
  return <TextField
    errorText={touched ? error : ''}
    fullWidth
    floatingLabelText={label}
    type={type}
    {...input}
  />
};

export class DialogComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      onSubmit,
      open,
      closeDialog,
    } = this.props;

    const actions = (cancel, confirm) => [
      <FlatButton
        label="Cancel"
        onClick={cancel}
      />,
      <FlatButton
        label="Submit"
        onClick={confirm}
      />
    ];

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>
          <Dialog
            // various stuff
          >
            <Field
              name='name'
              component={renderTextField}
              type="text"
              label="Name"
              style={styles}
            />
            // Other fields, eventually
          </Dialog>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

DialogComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

DialogComponent = connect(
  (state) => ({
    formInfo: state.formInfo
  })
)(DialogComponent);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myDialog'
})(DialogComponent)
```

I've tried tweaking configurations and exports 8 ways to Sunday, to no success. The result is always the same:
`Uncaught Error: Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`

I've been poking at this for a week or so now, so thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround, but it's a tad clunky. I had to split out the form itself, and re-inject the provider. Something about the Dialog changed the context. Also important is the order of the two decorators, reduxForm and connect. In the lowest level component, it has to be decorated with reduxForm *before* connect is called, or else the form won't have access to the store. The various reduxForm features all seem to work.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect, Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm } from 'redux-form';
import configureStore from './configureStore';

export class DialogComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const store = configureStore;

    return (
          <Dialog 
            // various props
          >
            <Provider store={store}>
              <FormComponent
                handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
                onSubmit={onSubmit}
              />
           </Provider>
          </Dialog>
    );
  }
}

DialogComponent.propTypes = propTypes;

DialogComponent = connect(
  (state) => ({
    formInfo: state.formInfo
  })
)(DialogComponent);

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myDialog'
})(DialogComponent)
```

And the spun out form content itself:

```
// FormComponent.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect} from 'react-redux';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';

// Widgets, etc
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

const propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  initialValues: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const renderTextField = ({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { asyncValidating, touched, error }
}) => {
  return <TextField
    errorText={touched ? error : ''}
    fullWidth
    floatingLabelText={label}
    type={type}
    {...input}
  />
};

export class FormComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      onSubmit,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={customTheme}>
            <Field
              name='name'
              component={renderTextField}
              type="text"
              label="Name"
              style={styles}
            />
            // Other fields, eventually
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

FormComponent.propTypes = propTypes;
FormComponent = reduxForm(
  form: 'myDialog',
  validate
})(FormComponent);

// Super important that connect comes AFTER reduxForm decorator
FormComponent = connect(
  (state) => ({
    formInfo: state.formInfo
    initialValues: { ...state.myInitialValues }
  })
)(FormComponent);

export default FormComponent;
```